# How do I verify that the ETag is valid if the user does not pass If-None-Match?

Tags: java, rest, jira, etag

My first time ever hearing of 'ETag'. From what I have been able to determine with the system I'm on, the system uses eTags to validate that the item being submitted has not been altered prior to the submission of the changes. If another user has modified the item then the system responds that the ETag is invalid. The users are using the REST services that had been created for the project and have not been altered in a couple years. I'm working on a JIRA based Java application which has REST services plugins.

Now as for what to do in regards to the ETag, I'm at a loss here.
Our security scan on the system marks the header ETag as a risk for injection of code. Perhaps I'm over-thinking this but,

1. Is the ETag created and set by some code in the application or is it created by the Tomcat server?
2. Am I to take the value of the ETag and compare it to something to
   make sure that it is valid?
3. How do I validate that the value for the
   ETag is valid?
4. Where does the validation even occur if the If-None-Match were provided by the request?
5. How do I protect it from injection?

I've been reading posts on this forum about things dealing with the ETag but I'm not understanding what/how I am to do anything with the ETag from step 1 to whatever the last step is.

### Could really use a reference as to how I'm to code to this.

Listing Resources I find:

- [ETag - HTTP Conditional Requests](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7232.html#header.etag)

Comment: Trusting the etag is effectively no more/less secure than trusting any other query parameter. (Well, perhaps a teeny bit more 'secure' as the header can't be set from JavaScript XHR.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is the ETag created and set by some code in the application or is it created by the Tomcat server?

If the server is Tomcat and the request is for static file on Tomcat server, yes, it is created by Tomcat. If the server is apache httpd and the request is for static file, yes. The ETag calculation algorithm of Tomcat and apache httpd differs. There is no standard specification for ETag calculation.

If the request is for not static file, Etag can/may be added to response HTTP header.

> Am I to take the value of the ETag and compare it to something to make sure that it is valid?

As for client side, you can compare ETag value to the other HTTP response's (usually of the same URL).

As for server side, you can compare If-Non-Match to what should be responded as ETag value. If the value matches, you should respond HTTP 304.

> How do I validate that the value for the ETag is valid?

Usually the server validates Etag. You can calculate ETag value for every each request. But it is more usual that ETag values are cached on the server.

> Where does the validation even occur if the If-None-Match were provided by the request?

It depends on the server implementation.

> How do I protect it from injection?

ETag value itself does not inject anything. But it can be used for the HTTP request tracking like Cookie. See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag#Tracking_using_ETags).

Comment: Is the ETag something that is just for the server to use and there is nothing for me to do with it in code?

 1. The server is Tomcat. The request is NOT for a static file.

 2. On server side, if the user does not provide If-Non-Match then what am I to do?

Comment: ETag is usually meant for the server to determine whether response is 304 or not. ETag/If-None-Match can be used for dynamic response, not only for static file. If the client send no If-None-Match, the server cannot determine whether the client have not received ETag or the client intentionally ignores ETag. But ordinary browsers automatically send If-None-Match if ETag have been received.

Comment: Several things are unclear to me regarding the ETag parameter.  
At what point does the server create the ETag?  
How is the server generating an ETag for a database entry?  
How is the server validating the ETag against the database entry?  
If the server is dealing with the creation and validation of the ETag and not the server side code for the application then why would this be a vulnerability reported to me and not something that the SA would be responsible for?

Comment: I have already mentioned that ETag calculation algorithms differ. As for apache httpd, for example, it comes from i-node by default. If using i-node as ETag value, there's no need to have specific database. It is instantly supplied from filesystem. As for tomcat, it comes from calculating hash. ETag value can be retrieved or re-calculated if the request is for static file. If calculation is heavy, it has to be cached. So it may stored as a database entry. Etag should be related to URL, so if storing, key should be URL (or maybe just path) and value should be Etag.

Comment: I cannot tell you anything about the vulnerability report unless you show me the detail of the report.

Comment: This is what was stated in the report: `The method doPut() in RestProjectXUtility.java includes unvalidated data in an HTTP response header on line 223. This enables attacks such as cache-poisoning, cross-site scripting, cross-user defacement, page hijacking, cookie manipulation or open redirect.`

But this is not what I'm needing to understand at this moment. Is there some site that has a UML or flow diagram that can explain how exactly step by step the process even occurs? I need to understand what goes on at each step of the request and response.

Comment: [This site](https://www.oclc.org/developer/develop/worldshare-platform/architecture/resource-versioning-using-etags.en.html) is a good explanation but doesn't have any diagrams. [This site](https://www.gliffy.com/publish/4683079/) has an instant diagram, but you need more precise details...perhaps.

Comment: I don't know how ETag response for PUT causes threat. From reading [this site](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-reschke-http-etag-on-write-latest.html), it seems that ETag response for PUT is relevant.